# Do Spreadtrum USB Drivers exist for Linux?

Tags: linux, kaios

I'm trying to connect to a KaiOS device with `adb` but whenever I run `adb devices` I get an empty list of devices, however when I run `lsusb` I get:

> Bus 001 Device 017: ID 1782:4001 Spreadtrum Communications Inc. Spreadtrum Phone

I've done all the pre-setup which include:

- Adding `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1782", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"` to /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
- Adding `0x1782` to ~/.android/adb_usb.ini
- Running `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`

But I still get an empty list (I'm on Linux to emphasize). I believe the issue may be that I need a spreadtrum drivers to connect to the device through `adb`. However I can't seem to find any spreadtrum drivers for Linux, they seem to only be available for Windows?

Comment: What's your device ?

Comment: @MathieuD. It's a KaiOS phone named "wowi" It's using KaiOS 2.5

Comment: I have the exact same situation (Linux adb not seeing device with lsusb ids 1782:4001) with a phone called Accent Nubia 50k

Comment: This page solved my issue: https://sites.google.com/view/bananahackers/devices/spreadtrum-based , I had to type the code `*#*#33284#*#*` on my phone for adb to list my Spreadtrum. Also, code `*#*#0574#*#*` enables a debug menu.
I can now see my phone on Kaiosrt WebIDE!